# How to display invalid email in authentication in ionic?

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, ionic2, angularfire

I'm making a login page and want it to show an alert message whenever the email or password entered by the user is not matched.

Also if the email or password is **not** matched then along with the displayed error, it should **not** go to the next page.

I've written a code which not only does **not** show the alert message, but also **goes** to the next page even if the user is **not authenticated**(i.e there is an error in the email and password entered)
Here is my code. Please Help !

```js
user= {} as User;

async login(user:User)
  {
   try
   {
      const result=this.angfire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);
      if(result)
      {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeManagerPage);
      }


   }
   catch(e)
   {
       var errorCode = e.code;
       var errorMessage = e.message;
       if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password')
       {
         alert('Wrong password.');
       } 
       else
       {
         alert(errorMessage);
       }
       console.log(e);


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know you'll always have a result with your code, it beeing an error or a success, so it'll always redirect to the page even if the login wasn't made. Try using the promise returned by the login method instead of the try/catch you use.

```
async login(user:User){
  this.angfire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
  .then(res => {
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomeManagerPage);
  }, err => {
    let msg;
    switch (err.code) { // SWITCH THE CODE RETURNED TO SEE WHAT MESSAGE YOU'LL DISPLAY
      case "auth/wrong-password":
        msg= "Email or Password is wrong.";
        break;

      case "auth/user-not-found":
        msg= 'User not found.'
        break;

      case "auth/invalid-email":
        msg= 'Email or Password is wrong.';
        break;
    }

    alert(msg);
  });
}
```

So, try always using promises returned by firebase/angularfire methods and you'll be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i'm getting an error which says '' Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.  ''

Comment: Only a slight correction i had to make was that , in the 'switch' condition, instead of 'error.code' i had to write ' error[ 'code' ] '

Answer (score 0):

Your function has the `async` keyword before it. `async`always returns a promise implicitly, and the resolve value of it will be whatever you `return` from the function (in this case `result`). As pointed in the previous answer, you always have a `result`, which in turn will direct you to the next page no matter what.
The whole point of using try/catch is to make use of `async` and `await`.Without `await` ,your try/catch will not be able to handle any synchronous and asynchronous errors.

Use this:

`const result=await this.angfire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password);`

The `catch` block will now come into play.